# In crystal reports how to number rows by letters

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to create an outline type numbering system in my crystal report with the following format:

1. text

   a. text

   b. text
2. text

   a.text

   b.text

   c. text

etc . I can generate 1,2,3 where I am using a,b c. Is there a crystal formula for converting 1 to a, 2 to b, etc or do I have to write one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use the crystal function `chrw` to convert int to char and an ascii table. (hint: a = 97)

```
chrw(96 + i) //where i is 1 based
```

or convert "a" to unicode with `ascw` and count up...

```
chrw(ascw("a") + (i-1)) //where i is 1 based
```

Comment: Hi, @dotjoe , what if my text interpretation is HTML? those codes wont work. Please help. thanks